# Angular: Find key/value in nested array

Tags: javascript, html, angular

**Description**:
I have a `module.ts` which has a const `route` which handles Routing.  In this route, I have a key under `data` called `sidebar`.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'devices',
  component: BaseComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: DeviceListComponent,
    data: {
      sidebar: true
    }
  }]
}];
```

**What I want to do:**
I want to be able to go through this array in my `component.ts` and if `sidebar` is found, and the value of `sidebar` is true, the `path` name will show up in a `div`.
For example, for `path:'device'`, `sidebar` is true, so my `div` will have a text in it saying `device`.

**What I tried to do/Problem(s):**
I can't figure out how to find the `sidebar` key.   In my `component.ts` file, I can succesfully get the array through `router.config`, but I can't figure out the logic to find the key.

```
ngOnInit() {     
  var theArray= this.router.config; //Grabs array successfully!
  for (let obj of theArray) {
    console.log("object:", theArray); //prints our array
    for (let sidebar in obj) {
      console.log("key:", sidebar, "value:", obj[sidebar]); 
    }
  }
}
```

The result I get from my second console.log is:

[image: console.log]

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is that you shouldn't be doing what you are doing :)
There is a way to achieve what you want to do, of course, by parsing the router config in some complicated way - but what you want to achieve, can be done way easier by using the intended way instead.

One way would be for example to use the resolve-data functionality of Angular in order to get the variable you need into your component.

So your route would look something like this

```
{
    path: '',
    component: DeviceListComponent,
    resolve: {
      sidebar: true
    }
}
```

whilst in your component you would do something like this

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hasSidebar= this.route.snapshot.data['sidebar'];
  }
```

for a more in-depth tutorial on that topic you might check out this blog post for example:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I was just typing the same thing! (But I left the `data` property to be `data` ... I'm not sure why you changed it to `resolve`?)

Comment: Why not simple in your component?   console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data);

Comment: @DeborahK yeah, data would have worked as well, you are right. just in case sidebar comes along async, we would need to use resolve

Comment: @Eliseo just because it's good practice to do your stuff in the ngOnInit and not in the constructor. in this simple example it will not make a difference, because we don't have any side effects, but as soon as you actually use it, you may face problems

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a more "Angular" way of doing this, but if not, you need to look deeper into that route object.

```
ngOnInit() {

    var theArray= this.router.config; //Grabs array successfully!

    for (let config of theArray) {
       const path = config.path;
       if ('children' in config) {
           const child = config['children'][0];
           if ('data' in child && child['data'].sidebar) {
               // do whatever you need in here
           }
       }
   }
}
```